# Javafx application (calculator) isn't working on other computers

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have made a calculator using javafx(I am a beginner). It worked fine on my computer. When I shared with my friend, only the stage was loaded like this...
[image: It seems as if fxml file cannot be loaded(I guess)]

Whereas, in computer...
[![This is it, a simple calculator][2]][2]

As a java programmer, this is my first project. It would be great, if you help me out with this...

Well, I have created this with Netbeans IDE, and there are three classes. **Calculate.java(to calculate) ,** **JavaFXApplication8.java(extends application) ,** **and FXMLDocumentController.java(to control FXML file)**

```java
public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        stage.setMaxHeight(350);
        stage.setMaxWidth(360);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Calculator");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        Image icon=new Image("Calculator-icon.png");        
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    public static String a="";

    private void SetLabel(ActionEvent event) {  
        result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void OnePressed(ActionEvent event) {
        a=a.concat("1");
        result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void TwoPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("2");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void ThreePressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("3");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void FourPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("4");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void FivePressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("5");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void SixPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("6");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void SevenPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("7");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void EightPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("8");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void NinePressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("9");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void ZeroPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat("0");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void PointPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=a.concat(".");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void DelPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a=Calculate.Del(a);
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void ACPressed(ActionEvent event) {
       a="";
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void AddPressed(ActionEvent event) { 
       a=a.concat("+");
       result.setText(a);
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void SubtractPressed(ActionEvent event) { 
       a=a.concat("-");
       result.setText(a);
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void MultiplyPressed(ActionEvent event) { 
       a=a.concat("*");
       result.setText(a);
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void DividePressed(ActionEvent event) { 
       a=a.concat("/");
       result.setText(a);
    }

    @FXML
    private void PercentPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(a.contains("/")){
            a=Calculate.divide(a);
            float percent=Float.valueOf(a);
            percent*=100;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(percent).concat("%"));
        }
        else{
            result.setText("Syntax error");
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void Result(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < a.length(); i++) {
              char ch=a.charAt(i);
                
             switch (ch) {
                 case '+':
                     a=Calculate.add(a);
                     result.setText(" = "+a);
                     break;
                 case '-':
                     a=Calculate.subtract(a);
                     result.setText(" = "+a);
                     break;
                 case '*':
                     a=Calculate.multiply(a);
                     result.setText(" = "+a);
                     break;
                 case '/':
                     a=Calculate.divide(a);
                     result.setText(" = "+a);
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
             }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result.setText("Syntax error");
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void SetLabel(MouseEvent event) {
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Calculate {
    public static String result;
    
    public static String add(String s){
        int d=0;
        String fist="";
        String secon="";
        
        char ch='+';
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch2=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch==ch2){
                fist=s.substring(0, i);
                secon=s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            }
        }
        float a=Float.valueOf(fist);
        float b=Float.valueOf(secon);
        float c=a+b;
        
        if(String.valueOf(c).endsWith(".0")){
             result=String.valueOf(c).substring(0, String.valueOf(c).length()-2);
        }
        else{
            result=String.valueOf(c);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String subtract(String s){
        String fist="";
        String secon="";
        
        char ch='-';
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch2=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch==ch2){
                fist=s.substring(0, i);
                secon=s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            }
        }
        float a=Float.valueOf(fist);
        float b=Float.valueOf(secon);
        float c=a-b;
       
        if(String.valueOf(c).endsWith(".0")){
             result=String.valueOf(c).substring(0, String.valueOf(c).length()-2);
        }
        else{
            result=String.valueOf(c);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String multiply(String s){
        String fist="";
        String secon="";
        
        char ch='*';
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch2=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch==ch2){
                fist=s.substring(0, i);
                secon=s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            }
        }
        float a=Float.valueOf(fist);
        float b=Float.valueOf(secon);
        float c=a*b;
       
        if(String.valueOf(c).endsWith(".0")){
             result=String.valueOf(c).substring(0, String.valueOf(c).length()-2);
        }
        else{
            result=String.valueOf(c);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String divide(String s){
        String fist="";
        String secon="";
        
        char ch='/';
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch2=s.charAt(i);
            if(ch==ch2){
                fist=s.substring(0, i);
                secon=s.substring(i+1, s.length());
            }
        }
        float a=Float.valueOf(fist);
        float b=Float.valueOf(secon);
        float c=a/b;
       
        if(String.valueOf(c).endsWith(".0")){
             result=String.valueOf(c).substring(0, String.valueOf(c).length()-2);
        }
        else{
            result=String.valueOf(c);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String Del(String s){
        int len=s.length();
        s=s.substring(0, len-1);
        return s;
    }
    }
```

It became a little bit lengthy, but please go through it. It is damn easy for anyone who can attempt answering it.

Comment: What is your JDK version and what is your friend's JDK version?

Comment: @arnabmaji19 I'm guessing that the class name (`JavaFXApplication8`) implies that the OP is using JDK 8.

Comment: How did you share it with your friend? Did you make a JAR file of your application and sent him the JAR? Does he also have _NetBeans_ and simply copied your code?

Comment: Yes, it is JDK 8

Comment: I first made a jar file with Netbeans, the with launch4j I made exe file. Then, I used install creator pro, to make installer than that installer I shared.

Comment: Did you try running the installer on your computer to see if it works on your machine?

Comment: Yes it worked on my computer.